# How to know If the given space is torsion free?

Tags: tensors, general-relativity

I'm given a metric
$$ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu=\left(1-\frac{r_g}{r}\right)c^2dt^2-\left(1+\frac{r_g}{r}\right)dr^2-r^2d\theta^2-r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2$$
where $r_g$ is a constant.

I'm trying to find, If
$$T^k_{ij}\equiv \Gamma^k_{ij}-\Gamma^k_{ji}$$
But the formula that I'm using that is
$$\Gamma^m_{ik}=\frac{1}{2}g^{ml}\left(\frac{\partial g_{li}}{\partial x^k}+\frac{\partial g_{lk}}{\partial x^i}-\frac{\partial g_{ik}}{\partial x^l}\right)$$

already assumes that the torsion tensor is zero. Can anyone help me out, How to see if $T^k_{ij}$ is zero or not?

Comment: You're right that the torsion (which btw is not a property of the space you're working on but rather the connection $\nabla$ you're using) in the case of the Levi-Civita connection (i.e the one given in terms of the metric) is always going to be $0$. So, there's nothing much to be proven here really. Maybe the goal of the exercise is for you to notice that the formula for $\Gamma^m_{ik}$ is already symmetric in the lower two slots, hence subtracting them is zero.

Comment: If you look at your expression for the metric $ds^2=g_{ij}dx^i dx^j$ you notice there are no mixed survivors $dx^idx^j$ for $i\neq j $. Under what circumstances can this be true?